# How to pass a method as a string and call it

Tags: ruby

I have a proc like so

```
Boxer = Proc.new { | box, goal | puts "  [#{ box }] #{ goal }" }
```

and I call it like so

```
Boxer[ 'X', goal ]
```

I would like to incorperate the ansi escape codes to change the color
I want to be able to pass in a string and have it print that color out
so my new Boxer would look like this

```
Boxer = Proc.new { |box, goal, color | puts "  [#{ box }] #{ goal }".color }
```

and I want to call it like so

```
Boxer[ 'X', goal, 'red' ]
```

I am using the colorize gem but still can't get the Proc to act like I want
I have tried eval and a couple other things.

Comment: What code would like to run? `['X']goal.red`? `goal['X'].red`? it is not very clear

Comment: I assume you mean for `Boxer` to be a constant. If you want a variable, have it begin with a lower case letter.

Comment: Boxer needs to constant. You guys are missing the point of what I was trying to do.

Comment: My comment was intended as an aside; I realized it was not central to the question. I mentioned it only because I often see questions where names of objects intended to be variables have been capitalized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try

```
Boxer = Proc.new { |box, goal, color | puts "  [#{ box }] #{ goal }".send(color) }
```

Comment: Good answer, +1, but Schylar, there's no need to select an answer quickly. By waiting at least a couple of hours, you might get other interesting answers that wouldn't be forthcoming if a selection has already been made. In my view, it's unprofessional to ask that one's answer be selected after such a short time.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It worked and thats all I needed. It isn't going into production for another week so it just needs to work for now so I can present what the final product will resemble. However, you made a good point so I will wait!